# Prevent ajax callback settimeout from executing more than once per click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I have a button, where when you click it, it will show the time, wait 5 seconds, show the time again, and then repeats indefinitely. However, if you click the button again, it'll call the function again, so now there are 2 of the ajax calls running at the same time. So instead of waiting 5 seconds and showing the time, since there are 2 of the ajax calls running at the same time. So depending on when you clicked the button on the second time, it may wait for 2 seconds, show the time, wait for 3 seconds, show the time, repeats indefinitely.

I thought of making the button unclickable once it was clicked, but I can't do that because I plan to add to the button other functions other than the ajax setTimeout callback, and that won't work out if I make the button unclickable. So, my question is, is there a way to cancel the first ajax call before calling the second ajax call, somehow?

**test1.php**

```
<style>
#output {
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<input type = 'submit' value = 'show time' onclick = "showTime('test2.php', 'output')">
<div id = 'output'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function showTime(gotoUrl,output) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: gotoUrl,
error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
success:function(data) {
document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;

setTimeout(function(){showTime(gotoUrl, output)}, 5000);

} //end of success:function(data)
}); //end of $.ajax

} //end of function ajaxFunc(gotoUrl, output)

</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$time = date('H:i:s');
echo $time;

?>
```

Comment: We don't want a wall of text or your entire program. We want the smallest possible program that reproduces the situation you're asking about and a clear problem statement.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns an instance id. You can store that id somewhere and if needed, call `clearTimeout(timeoutID)` to clear the timeout if it is waiting. That will make it so additional clicks will make the timeout restart with subsequent clicks.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I would need more to go on, like examples, to complete this task.

Comment: I guess you would also have to decide how you want to handle this. On second click, do you want the first one to be nullified and another 5 second timer to start? Or do you want the second click to be ignored, just waiting the 5 seconds from the first click. Essentially making it so while a timer is counting down from setTimeout clicks are ignored.

Comment: *"I thought of making the button unclickable once it was clicked, but I can't do that because I plan to add to the button other functions other than the ajax setTimeout callback, and that won't work out if I make the button unclickable. So, my question is, is there a way to cancel the first ajax call before calling the second ajax call, somehow?"* Please expand on this. The best way to solve your problem would be with .one(), however using .one() will impact how you do the other things.

Answer (score 2):

This took more than a few edits, but i'm kind of rushing. It should be along these lines:

```
var $element = $('selector');

//add event handler on click
$element.click(function () {
    //set up indefinite ajax call
    setInterval(function (){
        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           data: somedata,
           method: 'get'
        }).done(function (data) {
           //do something
        });
    }, 5000);
    //now we can remove the click event from the button
    $element.off('click');
});

//now we can add new ones using the reference
$element.on(//do whatever you want);
```

Comment: Why the upvote? (to be clear, wasn't my downvote either)

Comment: The upvote was from me, because it seemed like a decent answer. @Vikk i know you didnt downvote yourself - i was commenting to whoever downvoted your answer, in case i had missed some fundamental flaw in it.

Comment: I didn't down vote it either, but it would be nice if you explain each components in detail with comments. Assume that I know little to nothing about what each elements are doing. It would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @frosty so, you want him to explain what **your code**
 is doing?

Comment: his code is your code. all he added was an if statement and a call to a standard function that is well documented.

Comment: I am not sure why it got downvoted, This is a small variation in some production code I actually use. If there is anything unclear, I can add additional explanation or code.

Comment: @KevinB Well first of all, the first variable. Why is there nothing assigned to it? First confusion. I have more question, but let's just explain that first.

Comment: because it will be used later, and needs to persist for all calls to the event.

Comment: Why do you have the $.ajax <b> inside </b> the settimeout?

Comment: good point. that actually makes his answer not work. It will send the ajax request once, after 5 seconds, and not repeat.

Comment: well, the fact that it's a click event handler is more the cause of that, rather than where the ajax call is located. but the ajax call inside of the setTimeout causes it to run 5 seconds after the click, where as with your code it runs instantly, and then again 5 seconds later.

Comment: @KevinB Wait. Now you're confusing me. So are you saying that it will or WON'T work?

Comment: The code will work, it just won't do what you're trying to do. so, i guess it depends on what your definition of "is working" is

Comment: Ah I missed the point about wanting the infinite calling. This is set to clear the previous time out within a few seconds. I'll update it.

Comment: @KevinB So you're saying the code will run, but it won't answer the question?

Comment: Also, instead of "type" you're using "method"? And why is the success outside of the $.ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If you store the response from `setTimeout()` in a variable you can cancel it next time the button is clicks with the `clearTimeout()` method.

```
clearTimeout(myShowTime);
myShowTime = setTimeout(function(){showTime(gotoUrl, output)}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xhr.abort(); method to abort the ajax call like this:

```
var xhr;

function showTime(gotoUrl, output) {
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.abort();
    }
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: gotoUrl,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success:function (data) {
            document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
            setTimeout(function() {
                showTime(gotoUrl, output)
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery `.off()` to unbind one handler:

> http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: If you are going to use `off`, why not just use `one` to have it fire once. And you should probably mention that you would need to re-register the event if you want it to fire after the callback is done.